# json_encode() in eclipse php causes Call to undefined function json_encode() error

Tags: php, eclipse, json, eclipse-pdt

I have created a php project in the eclipse pdt. When I attempt to call 
java_encode, I get a "Call to undefined function json_encode()" error.
Other functions in the PDT's php core api do not do this.

Here is a code

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The second line causes the error. Do I need an include or require?
I am new to using json with the eclipse PDT. Help is needed. Thank you!

Comment: What version of PHP are using? And `json_encode` or `java_encode`? Is `java_encode` is just a typo?

Comment: Please check the PHP version, the [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) came with version 5.2.0 if you are installing the correct version maybe eclipse is pointing at the wrong direction !

Comment: as others have said, check your PHP version. `json_encode` is a perfectly valid PHP function, as long as you're using PHP 5.2 and up. If you're using an older version, you *really* need to upgrade, because even 5.2 has been out of support for two years, and 5.1 was obsolete several years before that.

Comment: Check in your PDT Setting which PHP version is used to check the PHP code.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-json`

Answer (score 2):

On Linux systems, sometimes you need to add `extension=json.so` to your php.ini file.

Please make sure that you add it to the correct php.ini, the one that is used by your PHP command line interpreter (CLI). For example: `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

Comment: lots of answers but this is the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open

```
Preferences -> PHP -> PHP Interpreter
```

Then make sure at least PHP 5.2 is selected! If it is not available then you will need to update your PDT installation:

```
Help -> Check for updates
```

Comment: I typed in java_encode by mistake. I meant json_encode. I an using php 5.4. It still does not work. I am also using zend debugger. It raises same error when I do a simple Run rather than a Debug. I

Comment: Is is a problem that my apache server uses php 5.1.4 from phpinfo() ...Apache/2.0.58 (Win32) PHP/5.1.4